# Collapsible Jtable

Tags: java, swing

Have anyone implemented something similar to Excel's collapsible levels structure? UI should like same as Image. Remember Tree Table is not acceptable.  Can any one help me how can I create this.

[image]

Comment: just interesting why isn't TreeTable acceptable, and in which details/funcionalities is contingent table so different, that's only my question, nobody knows maybe there exists another options

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Excels table works and I can't tell from the image what the feature are that you require.

Maybe [Table Filtering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) can do what your want.

Or maybe StanislavL's [Envelope Table](http://java-sl.com/envelope.html) can help you out.